# error when i used my ip address instead of localhost as URL

Tags: php, networking

I have downloaded WAMP server and i have written a very very simple php code and saved it in

> C:\wamp\www\php_lear

folder. I have tested it using chrome giving url as

> {localhost/php_lear/eg2.php}

And it worked fine. This uses a database stored in phpmyadmin. I found out my ip address from google  117.195.230.41. When i give

> {117.195.230.41/php_lear/eg2.php}

as URL it gives me 404 not found

> "The requested URL '/php_lear/eg2.php' was not found on this server"

Please help. I have no knowledge of ips and urls and very new to this field and yeah i have added this ip as allowed user in phpmyadmin. I actually want to use this in my android app.

Comment: That's your public IP, so you're probably accessing the files from your router instead of your computer.

Comment: You are probably making it to a different virtual host. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: Im not familiar with WAMP, but it's probably the problem of apache configuration file.

Comment: Also, you may need to forward traffic to port 80 (or whatever you are using) to your computer (by mac or ip) from you router/modem/wifi/etc...

Comment: @Mike what do u mean by accesing the files from "router" or "computer"...can u please be more specific as i am very new to all of this...or can u please provide me any links which will make me understand better...

Comment: To add on to @Orangepill, [This link](http://guides.jlbn.net/setaccess/setaccess1.html) explains how to set up WAMP for external access also.

Comment: @petter unfortunately i did not get a single word of yours :( ..but thanks for ur reply

Comment: @acoder If you have a router you need to instruct the router to forward the traffic it receives on port 80 (i.e. HTTP) to you computer/server. How you do that depends on your router.

Comment: @acoder what petter said. That's what I meant by accessing files on your router instead of your computer.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address you get from google is the IP address of your router. It does not point to your computer. As some ppl said, besides there is different ports to use in a connection and your WAMP installation is "listening" on the port 80 of your computer (127.0.0.1)

When you access to the 117.195.230.41 you are accessing to the IP that your Internet Service Provider gives to your installation. So you need to access your router and redirect all the querys to the 117.195.230.41 on port 80 to your port 80 and the IP of your computer in your local network.

Answer (score 1):

The Public/Private IP confusion is a common misunderstanding.

Mike is correct. Due to how IP addressing works, there's a limited number of addresses. As a result, Network Address Translation was born (among other irrelevant things). The Public IP is what the world sees when it glances at your traffic. You want your Private IP, the one your router's DHCP has given you.

1) Open command prompt.

2) Issue the command "ipconfig" (without the quotes).

3) Find your "IPv4 Address". That's the one you want.

Additionally, follow Surt's suggestion to get everything working properly.